If a man says to a woman ｢ちょっと待てよ!!｣, will it sound like a commanding tone or a rude tone?
From what I know, "ちょっと待てよ" is pretty rude and if a man uses it towards a woman, they should at least be a couple or married, but what about partners or crew? I'd like to know a little more about this word.
Just for context, I saw this moment in a manga, there was a moment where a woman and a man (the woman is about 10 years older than the man and they are not romantically involved) were crew members and when the woman decided to leave the crew for good, the man yelled her ｢ちょっと待てよ!!｣. So I wondered if it sounded rude and if the man was using a commanding tone.

Generally, regardless of the listener's gender or age, this is not an appropriate expression to use in a workplace. In a workplace setting, it would only be heard when someone is so angry that they cannot control their emotions and has forgotten politeness and keigo completely.
Even among family members, this type of imperative form is not normally used unless the speaker is angry or has a rebellious attitude.
If the above explanation doesn't fit your situation, you might want to check if they said 待ってよ rather than 待てよ. While 待ってよ isn't keigo either, it has a much milder tone.
